# Unity 2018: 2D Object - SpriteMesh

Tags: unity-game-engine

Ok, so I have looked around the internet but I cannot find the sprite mesh. I should be able to right click my sprite> 2D Object> SpriteMesh.

Problem is that I don't see the option "SpriteMesh" anywhere.

Here's the deal. I created a bunch of 2D pieces for a character: head, body, two arms, two legs, two hands, and two feet. I imported the sprite as a PNG file and changed SpriteMode to multiple. I used the Sprite Editor to slice the char into pieces automatically. There's also nothing inside of the sprite editor that allows me to rig bones either.

Now I need to Rig the toon with bones and skin. However, I cannot find a way to do this. Watching a few tutorials, the guy adds a SpriteMesh to each of the parts. However, when I try to do this, the option just doesn't exist. I see SpriteMask but no SpriteMesh.

I'm using Unity 2018.2.18f1.

I have zero experience in animations like this. Normally I create a player/enemy without legs/arms. So they just float and I use the animation tab to change size/shape to insinuate movement. However, I'd like to take this next step and make the game look better.

How can I rig my toon? What steps do I need to follow?
All help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you're referring to Anima2D (Which uses SpriteMesh). It is different from the 2D Animation package which uses SpriteSkin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to use the new 2D Features from Unity, if you want to rig your 2D Character.

> I'm using Unity 2018.2.18f1.

- **You need to use Unity 2018.3 or later to use these tools.**

I suggest you to use **Unity Hub** to download multiples versions and Beta versions.

There is [a really nice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXIuizGzY2A) from Brackeys about this subject also.

When you have the 2018.3 or later version installed, open your project and go to the Window/Package Manager window, you need to install these packages :

[image: Packages]

I don't think you need the 2D Pixel Perfect but it's always nice to have.

Comment: Ok, this was the perfect answer for me. I thank you very much! I've been subscribed to Brackeys for years so I'm surprised I haven't seen this video before! The thing that threw me off here is the fact that I litterally just updated my Unity version two days ago and assumed I had the latest edition. I was going to hold out until 2019 comes out, but got tired of seeing the "update" pop up everytime I opened my Unity.Anyway, thanks for the response! Hopefully your answer will help many others down the road!

Comment: I'm getting a weird compiling error since I downloaded the 2D Animation pack. (I downloaded all four packs you suggested). Now my program can't run at all and I reimported the 2D Animation to try to see if that would help. However, it did not. Perhaps you know about this error and can help?

Comment: /Desktop/Unity5.2/2D/Platformers/TheProject904/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.2d.animation@1.0.16-preview.2/Runtime/SpriteSkin.cs(195,47): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Sprite' does not contain a definition for `GetBoneWeights' and no extension method `GetBoneWeights' of type `UnityEngine.Sprite' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: You should open a new question for that, are you using the Experimental API ? 
It looks like the method you are trying to use is from the SpriteDataAccessExtension class : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Experimental.U2D.SpriteDataAccessExtensions.html

Comment: I will ask unity and see if anything is known. I am using 2019 beta so who knows? Animating with this feature is so much easier, so I'm getting a bit discouraged. I'm not suffering from a user issue, but software malfunction instead. I feel extremely limited to what I can do at this point, and it's just all around frustrating. However, giving up isn't an option for me, so maybe I'll take a couple days off and recoup? Thank's for all of your assistance!

Comment: I feel you, I have the same with UIElements, it's in experimental state and don't have enough resources to know exactly how to use it.. But be patient, it will be released one day or another.

Comment: I decided to create a simple char, basically a circle with a face to use in the meantime while I figure out how to get this animation 2D rig to work. I was very much looking forward to this feature!